# Returning parsed JSON data using Alamofire?

Tags: swift, alamofire

Hello new to Swift and Alamofire,

The issue i'm having is when I call this fetchAllUsers() the code will return the empty users array and after it's done executing it will go inside the AF.request closure and execute the rest.

I've done some research and I was wondering is this is caused by Alamofire being an Async function.

Any suggestions?

```
func fetchAllUsers() -> [User] {
    var users = [User]()
    
    let allUsersUrl = baseUrl + "users/"
    
    if let url = URL(string: allUsersUrl) {
        AF.request(url).response { response in
            if let data = response.data {
                users = self.parse(json: data)
            }
        }
    }
    return users        
}
```

Comment: yes you are right.

Comment: @TusharSharma is there a way to disable async on alamo or am i going about this in a wrong way

Comment: You are making an async network call which will take some time to return results. So you don’t want your app to be stuck for that amount of time and create bad user experience. Async will invoke return statement straight after starting, and return call to main thread. Meanwhile your API call is running in background thread, and once completed call goes inside closure block as you witnessed. I would suggest you to look at @escaping closure as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the asynchrony in some way. This this means passing a completion handler for the types you need. Other times it means you wrap it in other async structures, like promises or a publisher (which Alamofire also provides).

In you case, I'd suggest making your `User` type `Decodable` and allow Alamofire to do the decoding for you.

```swift
func fetchAllUsers(completionHandler: @escaping ([User]) -> Void) {
    let allUsersUrl = baseUrl + "users/"
    
    if let url = URL(string: allUsersUrl) {
        AF.request(url).responseDecodable(of: [User].self) { response in
            if let users = response.value {
                completionHandler(users)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I would suggest returning the full `Result` from the response rather than just the `[User]` value, otherwise you'll miss any errors that occur.

Comment: I'm going to use @TusharSharma solution of using an escaping closure as a paramter. Call this function and create the array inside my viewModel